# How to convert utf-8 to string

Tags: java, utf-8

I read *Arabic data* from a *2d barcode* and the result was like this:

```
ÚÞÈå#ÚÈæÏ#ÝæÇÒ#ÇÈÊÓÇã#ÈÊíÓå
```

How do I get the original string from this encoded string?

Comment: Can you tell us which library you use? Do you have some example code?

Comment: This looks more like it is ISO8859-1 character encoding instead of UTF-8. So maybe you got bytes without setting an Encoding? Which Java Version do you use < 9 or >= 9?

Comment: the string was result of scanning pdf417 barcode, I am not sure that this is UTF-8 so please your kind advise, I am using less than 9 java version

Comment: the string was result of scanning pdf417 barcode, I am not sure that this is UTF-8 so please your kind advise